# Small difference in page views within BigQuery and GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, pageviews

I'm querying page views by page from BigQuery. My query is:

```
SELECT hits.page.pagePath, COUNT(*) as pageViews FROM `bigquery-refresh.refresh.ga_sessions_2015*`,
UNNEST(hits) as hits
WHERE date >= '20150101' AND date < '20150701'
AND geoNetwork.country = "United States"
AND hits.type="PAGE"
GROUP BY hits.page.pagePath
ORDER BY pageViews DESC
```

I'm comparing this query to the total page views reported from within GA (for the same country and date range), and am finding that the total number of page views in GA is ~0.4% larger than in BigQuery. Is there a reason for this small discrepancy?

Comment: `count` is approximative in BigQuery it's not exact

Comment: `COUNT` is exact, not approximate. Maybe you are thinking of `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` in legacy SQL? To the original question, though, is it possible that the discrepancy is due to the metrics in GA including some extra data from the end? I'm curious whether there is still a discrepancy if you restrict the range e.g. to only the month of July.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Yes, they match exactly for the month of July.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with GA, but here are my random guesses:
(1) As Elliott pointed out, maybe GA includes some extra data
(2) Or maybe GA uses different rule than count(*)
(3) I happen to know that Adwords will adjust the report data even several days later. Maybe GA has the same feature.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're counting the right thing?

On the [Schema documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) it says that each row in BQ corresponds to a session (not a hit, nor a pageview), so the count(*) wouldn't be correct and thus show a different number when compared to GA's UI.

The schema also shows that for pageviews you have the totals:

- totals.pageviews (check definition [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6086080?hl=en))
- totals.hits (check definition [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6086082?hl=en))

So, every interaction with the page is a hit. Can you confirm that by using the totals.pageviews you get to the correct number?